# latex2blender latex installation

Tags: add-on, linux

Hi I'm trying to use the wonderful package

https://github.com/ghseeli/latex2blender

But I'm not sure how to tell the plugin where the latex program is.

[image]

Do you have an idea? I have latex installed but I'm not sure what file exactly or path the program is looking for. I tried a lot of different stuff, such as `/usr/bin/latex`. I'm using a Linux Mint sytem.

Comment: Since that's an external addon and not part of Blender you'll have to ask the author directly. I assume you've seen the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/ghseeli/latex2blender/wiki/Installation)? - This Q&A site can only help with questions about using Blender itself and its built-in addons.

Comment: You are right @JohnEason I'm trying my luck on unbuntu stackexhange. I was hoping someone here might have tried the plugin as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
In linux, I had installed latex via apt install, but blender was installed differently. Installing blender though apt as well fixed this.